# Delay and Reclicking for Showing User media

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, getusermedia

**PROBLEM: **

I am trying to  take user  media once the user clicks on the button,  ' enter the room ', and after that, his video   (user media  ) will be  shown,

but  when I click on the  button  place for user media video is occupied and the button gets shifted but no video appears
and when I click again, then only the video is shown

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react'

import styles from './userVideo.module.css'

function UserVideo() {
    const video = useRef();

    const [stream, setStream] = useState()
    



    const constraints = {
        audio: true,
        video: {
            width: 500,
            height: 300
        }
    }
    const getUserMedia = () => {

        
        alert(" getUser Media is called ")
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: true }).then((stream) => {
          
            setStream(stream)
            video.current.srcObject = stream


        })
        


    }







    return (
        <div className={styles.userVideoOuterContainer} >
           


            <button onClick={getUserMedia} className={styles.enterRoomButton}>
                Enter Room
            </button>
            {stream && <video  muted ref={video} autoPlay style={{ width: "300px" }} />}

        </div>
    )
}

export default UserVideo
```

**SCREEN SHOTS enter image description here**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The video be rendered before ref video.current set stream so the first time click to button video.current.srcObject = stream not work. You try let

`video.current.srcObject = stream` to `useEffect` has stream is dependencies like below code. Option 1:

```
const getUserMedia = () => {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: true }).then((stream) => {
        setStream(stream)
    })
}
useEffect(() => {
  if(video.current){
    video.current.srcObject = stream
  }
}, [stream])
```

Option 2: You can let the condition to render `video` to CSS

```
<video  muted ref={video} autoPlay style={{ width: "300px", display: display: stream ? "block" : "none" }} />
```

Comment: I st Option gives the error  "   Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'srcObject') "  and  fives white screen . While 2nd Option dooes not solve the purpose  .

Comment: Sorry I missing validate video.current before set srcObject. you can try [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-e836hq?file=src/Modal.js)

Comment: As Per your Last comment, you  were pointing toward the platform, but I think you missed  to give any solution for the  problem  that was occurring in the  first approach